# Does it matter if you don't learn the latest verion of a Java?

Tags: java, java-12

At the moment I am learning Java 9, despite Java 12 being the latest version. Is this an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not at all. There is no significant difference between Java 8,9,11 and 12.
Yes, there are some cool features in 12, for example local type inference and also some new collections api's, but really nothing that a beginner could benefit from.

Just try to learn Java 8 (or 9; basically the same) and then you can move on (or not) to newer releases.
Why I said "or not" is because newer versions of Java (starting w/ 11 if I'm not mistaken) do not have free support any more. That's right, Oracle is now charging to give you support and also you are not allowed to use it commercially without paying a huge fee.

Due to this reason, many companies still use Java 8 or 9, so you should be okay.

Comment: The Java SE edition is free, so is it the Java Enterprise which is not free anymore?

Comment: Nope. Java SE also requires a subscription for version 11 and up https://www.oracle.com/java/java-se-subscription.html